# Total variation and relative $\ell_\infty$ metric

Tags: probability-distributions

Let 
$$D_{tv}(P,Q) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{a \in A}|P(a)-Q(a)|$$
and
$$D_{\infty}(P,Q) = \sup_{a \in A} \log \max\{\frac{P(a)}{Q(a)}, \frac{Q(a)}{P(a)}\},$$
where $P$ and $Q$ denote probability measures on a finite set $A$.

Can you show that
$$D_{tv}(P,Q) \leq 1- \exp(-D_{\infty}(P,Q)) \leq D_{\infty}(P,Q)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $1- \exp(-D_{\infty}(P,Q)) \leq D_{\infty}(P,Q)$ is just an instance of the elementary inequality $e^u\ge1+u$ for all real $u$.

Let us show an improved version of the inequality $D_{tv}(P,Q) \leq 1- \exp(-D_{\infty}(P,Q))$, namely,
\begin{equation*}
 D_{tv}(P,Q) \leq 1- \exp(-D_{1,\infty}(P,Q)), 
\end{equation*}
where 
\begin{equation*}
 D_{1,\infty}(P,Q) := \sup_{a \in A} \ln\frac{P(a)}{Q(a)}
 \le D_{\infty}(P,Q). 
\end{equation*}

Indeed, for brevity let $r:=\exp D_{1,\infty}(P,Q)[\ge1]$. Then $Q(a)\ge \frac1r\,P(a)$ for all $a\in A$. So, substituting $x=P(a)-Q(a)$ into the identity $x_+:=\max(0,x)=\frac12\,(|x|+x)$ for all real $x$ and using the identity $\sum_{a \in A}(P(a)-Q(a))=0$, we have 
\begin{multline*}
 D_{tv}(P,Q) = \sum_{a \in A}(P(a)-Q(a))_+
 \le\sum_{a \in A}(1-\tfrac1r)P(a)=1-\tfrac1r \\ 
 =1- \exp(-D_{1,\infty}(P,Q)), 
\end{multline*}
as desired.